# how to find elements with the same class names using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, xhtml

I have a container and inside that I have several anchor tags. These anchor tags has same class names. Now I want to get all anchor tags with class name lets say clickMe inside container. and apply a plugin to only them.

here is what I have

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="button" rel="btn1">Task box 1</a><br />
    <a href="#" class="button" rel="btn2">Task box 2</a><br />
    <a href="#" class="button" rel="btn3">Task box 3</a><br />
    <a href="#" class="button" rel="btn4">Task box 4</a><br />
    </div>
```

**EDIT**

Here is my plugin code

```
(function() {
$.fn.tasks = function(userOptions){
    this.each(function() {
        var opts = $.extend({
            'speed'     : 200
        }, userOptions);

        var ael = $(this).find('a.button');
        var container = $(this); //'.' + opts.container;
        var speed = opts.speed;
        //alert(container);
        var backdrop = $('<div></div>').addClass('backdrop');
        var box = $('<div></div>').addClass('box');

        $(ael).click(function() {
            //alert(speed);
            var rel = $(this).attr(rel);
            alert("rel");
            $(box).html(rel);
            $(container).append(backdrop, box);
            $(backdrop).animate({'opacity' : '.50'}, speed, 'linear');
            $(box).animate({'right' : '0'}, speed, 'linear');
            $(backdrop,box).css('display', 'block');
        });

        $(backdrop).click(function() {
            closeBox();
        });

        function closeBox() {
            $(box).animate({'right' : '-500'}, speed, 'linear', function() {
                $(backdrop).animate({'opacity' : '.0'}, speed, 'linear', function() {
                    $(backdrop,box).css('display', 'none');
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
}(jQuery))
```

Comment: by reading the API doc and tutorials. The jquery home page even features an example! `$("p.neat").addClass("ohmy").show("slow");`

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/tutorials

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info *"When asking jQuery questions, you should: Read the jQuery API documentation carefully and search Stack Overflow for duplicates before asking"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, it's as simple as this:

```
$(".container a.clickMe").yourPlugin();
```

`.container` - Finds elements with class "container"

`a.clickMe` - Finds descendants of `.container` that are `a` elements with class "clickMe"

You should probably start (as mentioned in comments on your question) by reading the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/), as this is pretty much as basic as it gets.

**Edit** (see comments)

In your plugin, `this` will most likely refer to the set of matched elements. You can therefore iterate over `this` using `each`, and use `find` to get the descendant `a` elements:

```
this.each(function() {
    var aElems = $(this).find("a.clickMe");
});
```

Comment: Sorry what I meant to ask is the I will applu plugin to container and then my plugin will automatically get all the anchors inside that container and apply the click event and all functionality to that anchor tags.

Comment: I tried your way but it is not working. Please see the updated version of my post I added my plugin code.

Comment: What's not working? I'm not going to spend ages debugging all that code. Try to get it down to just the bit that's causing the problem. The general idea should work: http://jsfiddle.net/ee4tW/

Comment: I don't know how this question got from: *'how to select by class'* to: *'my plugin doesn't work'*.

Comment: The problem was with this line var rel = $(this).attr(rel); Thanks for your help. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

To select only the anchors with class of 'clickMe' inside the container use: `$("div.container a.clickMe")`